# Relation between inequalities $r + s > 2t$, $r > t$, $t>s$, and $r>s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is a GMAT question about relations between inequalities.

> If $r + s > 2t$, is $r > t$?

(1) $t > s$
(2) $r > s$

(A) Statement (1) ALONE is sufficient, but statement (2) alone is not sufficient.
(B) Statement (2) ALONE is sufficient, but statement (1) alone is not sufficient.
(C) BOTH statements TOGETHER are sufficient, but NEITHER statement ALONE is sufficient.
(D) EACH statement ALONE is sufficient.
(E) Statements (1) and (2) TOGETHER are NOT sufficient.

---

So how do we best evaluate statement 1. Is picking numbers and testing a viable strategy here? Why or why not? Are there just too many combinations to test?

I don't want to answer this myself and the method I took because I want to hear how the community thinks about this problem before trying to answer it themselves. What's step 1?

So, after much struggle, I know the answer is D. Both statements 1 and 2 are independently sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: If $t>s$, $r+s>2t>t+s$. If $r>s$, $2r>r+s>2t$.

Comment: How does the first part show sufficiency for 1?

Comment: If $r+s>t+s$ we can subtract $s$ from both sides of the inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $t  \gt s \implies -s \gt -t$. Add this to $r + s \gt 2t$ and get $r \gt t$.

   (if $a > b$ and $c > d$ then $a + c > b + d$).
2. $r > s  \implies r + r > r + s$, i.e. $2r > r +s > 2t$ so $r > t$.

   (if $a > b$ then $a + c > b + c$).